# scipy.optimise.bisect on a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, zero, bisect

I have a numpy array of floats which when printed look like this:
[image]

The red circles are the original values, the blue crosses are a linear interpolation using `numpy.interp`.

I would like to find the abscissa of the zero crossing of this numpy array (red circle) using `scipy.optimize.bisect` (for example). Since this is a numpy array (and not a function) I cannot pass it directly to `scipy.optimize.bisect`. So I was thinking to pass a function that interpolates the numpy array to bisect. Here is the code I am using for the moment:

```
def Inter_F(x,xp,fp):
    return np.interp(x,xp,fp)
Numpyroot = scp.optimize.bisect(Inter_F,0,9,args=(XNumpy,YNumpy))
```

I find a value that seems correct, Numpyroot = 3.376425289196618.
I am wondering:

- if this is the correct technical way to use scipy.optimize.bisect on
     a numpy array? Specially when I am going to do this 10^6 times on different set of numpy values.
- if enforcing a linear interpolation is not influencing the results
  that bisect is going to find and if yes, are there better choice?

Here are the two numpy arrays:

```
XNumpy = array([ 0.   ,  1.125,  2.25 ,  3.375,  4.5  ,  5.625,  6.75 ,  7.875,  9.   ])
YNumpy = array([ -2.70584242e+04,  -2.46925289e+04,  -1.53211676e+04,
        -2.30000000e+01,   1.81312104e+04,   3.41662461e+04,
         4.80466863e+04,   5.75113178e+04,   6.41718009e+04])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you do is correct. However, there is a more concise way.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


XNumpy = np.array([0., 1.125, 2.25, 3.375, 4.5, 5.625, 6.75, 7.875, 9.])
YNumpy = np.array([
    -2.70584242e+04, -2.46925289e+04, -1.53211676e+04,
    -2.30000000e+01, 1.81312104e+04, 3.41662461e+04,
    4.80466863e+04,   5.75113178e+04,   6.41718009e+04
]) 

invf = interp1d(YNumpy, XNumpy)
print(invf(0))
```

Result:

```
array(3.376425289199028)
```

Here I use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to return a function. Also I interpolate the inverse function so that the abscissa are readily calculated. Of course you can do the same trick with `np.interp`, I just like `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` because it returns a function so I can calculate `x` value from any given `y` value.

Comment: thanks. It work perfectly. What kind of algorithm is used in scipy.interpolate.interp1d ?

Comment: @gregory `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` supports various interpolating method. The default is linear, you can also specify higher order spline interpolator via the `kind` argument. You can find more details in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).